# Break existing code into java and android modules

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have created an Android app. To facilitate maintenance of the code, I want to break it into modules and move code to these modules. I know how to create modules in Android Studio 2.2.2.

I am not able to find any shortcut in the IDE to move the code (something like moving code to a different class using "Refactor" menu item) to the new module.

Comment: what kind of refactoring actions you need?

Comment: I am looking to "Move existing code to new module and update references if required".

Comment: you mean moving entire file or part of the code? to another package?

Comment: Moving entire files and packages to another module.

Comment: You can just make new packages and simply drag & drop your files with your project window. :))

Comment: Well... don't you want to write code for you?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the package or the file you want to move and drag and drop in the src package of the newly created module.